# Element location inside the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I'm trying to develop such thing as recording of user's actions on the website.

Assuming I have the next (simplified) HTML page, at which recording is performing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="somestyle.css" />
        <script src="myrecordscript.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button id="appearModal">appear modal window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, I send initial markup to the server, then create a `MutationObserver` that observes `document.documentElement`, so I have all the mutations observed inside the document.

With this JavaScript functions, for example, I can get the index path of inserted element

```
/* somewhere inside the ES6 class */
getElementIndex = (element) => {
    return element.parentElement ? [...element.parentElement.children].indexOf(element) : 0
}
getInsertedPath = (mutation) => {
    var target = mutation.addedNodes[0]
    var parent = (mutation.previousSibling || mutation.nextSibling) ? (mutation.previousSibling || mutation.nextSibling).parentElement : mutation.target
    var indexPath = []
    if (!parent)
        return indexPath

    if (!mutation.previousSibling)
        indexPath.push(-1)
    else
        indexPath.push(this.getElementIndex(target) - 1)

    while (parent) {
        indexPath.push(this.getElementIndex(parent))
        parent = parent.parentElement
    }

    return indexPath.reverse()
}
```

For example, assuming that modal window is appending at the end of `body`, `getInsertedPath` will return an array `[0, 1, 2]`, that means that I should insert modal's markup after the next element:

```
document.children[0].children[1].children[2]
```

And everything was fine until I found that different <s>foken awesome</s> awful browser's extensions are modifying the markup incorrectly. For example, Ghostery extension for Chrome adding extra `div` BETWEEN THE `head` and `body` (sic!), i.e. I got the next initial markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="somestyle.css" />
        <script src="myrecordscript.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="anotherAwesomeGhosteryButtonOrSomething"></div>
    <body>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button id="appearModal">appear modal window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

which results that `getInsertedPath` returns `[0, 2, 2]`.
Fine, sounds like there is no problem. But when I try to recreate recording from it's data, I got that when I insert an invalid HTML into `iframe`, browsers (tested in Chrome and Firefox) are automatically fixing it, and instead I got this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="somestyle.css" />
        <script src="myrecordscript.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="anotherAwesomeGhosteryButtonOrSomething"></div>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <button id="appearModal">appear modal window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it (obviously) breaks everything, because now I got `undefined` at `document.children[0].children[2]...`

Is there any other way to get the element position (more safely and more resistant to this kind of unexpected behaviours)?

Comment: Yes, through appropriate selector like class, id, tagname, attribute-name-value etc.